# ag-grid auto column size not working if font is big

Tags: ag-grid, autosize

When font size is big, auto-sizing (no matter in what way) trims the column data.

I tried it on **plnkr.com** link referred from: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-resizing/#

I styled the rows to have **20px font size** and since then the autosizing doesn't work properly.
 see in the image, country & date columns are cut in the middle after "Aut-Size all" and after double click to autosize a single column.
[plnkr sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hvYDc.jpg)

any ideas?

thanks

Comment: pls provide the plnkr link instead of screen-shot

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/FD1EjSz9D7zv8LCoRrW5?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix this by applying your `bigfont` class [via `cellClass`](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-styling/) instead:

https://plnkr.co/edit/qzwOYqN6ybXJns0xDvqy?p=preview

```
var gridOptions = {
    defaultColDef: {
        resizable: true,
        cellClass: 'bigfont',
    },
    columnDefs: columnDefs,
    rowData: null,
    //rowClass: 'bigfont',
    onColumnResized: function(params) {
        console.log(params);
    }
};
```

This is happening because to work out the width of a cell, ag-grid [clones it](https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/blob/3d14f9cc21fd8e9cda791ba0949568925160d64b/packages/ag-grid-community/src/ts/rendering/autoWidthCalculator.ts#L92). The cloned cell doesn't have some of the parent DOM structure, such as a row with your specified `rowClass`.

It's a marginal bug in ag-grid.

Related to this, on GitHub:

- https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/issues/2731
- https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/pull/915

Comment: Thank You! That is really helpful